# Group by having max time without subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by

I was wondering if someone can assist me with the following. Every business can have multiple notes. I need to get ONLY the notes with the most recent date, (one) for every business. This is what I tried, however this seems to produce incorrect results:

```
SELECT * FROM note n
GROUP BY business_id
HAVING MAX(`time`)
```

Is it possible to accomplish this **without** the use of a subquery?

I appreciate any suggestions, thanks in advance!

Comment: Similiar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Comment: The manual provides a solution, but what's wrong with subqueries?

Comment: Because providing the last note for every business is part of the application requirements that I must fulfill.

Comment: Strawberry, I am working with a very large dataset. A subquery approach will work as well, if it is not horrible in performance. I was just wondering if it is possible to accomplish this without one, but any solution will work really.

Comment: Both methods provided by Gordon are likely to be orders of magnitude faster than any 'no subquery' approach. Appropriately indexed, they *should* both be fast, but for aesthetic reasons I prefer the uncorrelated subquery (or 'traditional') method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method that might be relatively efficient with an index on `note(business_id, time)`:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM note n
WHERE not exists (select 1
                  from note n2
                  where n2.business_id = n.business_id and
                        n2.`time` > n.`time
                 );
```

The traditional method also works:

```
select n.*
from note n join
     (select business_id, max(time) as maxtime
      from note
      group by business_id
     ) nmax
     on n.business_id = nmax.business_id and n.`time` = nmax.maxtime;
```

But it has to do the aggregation as a separate step.  The first version should just be able to resolve the `where` clause using the index.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gordon. This may work but I have to say, wow, performance is horrible. 1 minute + and it is still not done querying (dataset is large 50k+). I don't think I can use this. Thanks anyways.

Comment: The traditional method from your above approaches is much better in terms of performance, will test and post back, I appreciate the help!

Comment: @AnchovyLegend . . . That is interesting.  Are you sure you have the index defined as specified?

Comment: +1, ended up using the traditional method. Thank you!

Comment: @AnchovyLegend . . . By the way, thank you for the feedback on performance.  I had thought the first method would be better with the appropriate index.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT n.*
FROM
  note n LEFT JOIN note n1
  ON n.business_id=n1.business_id
     AND n.`time` < n1.`time`
WHERE
  n1.business_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This may work, however, it is horrible with performance, I cannot use it.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend do you have any index on your table? but yes, subqueries are not always slower, sometimes they might perform better than a join...

Comment: Of course, the table is indexed. Please edit and add a subquery solution, if you have one. I appreciate the help.

Comment: This *is* the classic solution. I was once such a strong advocate of it that it's even referred to sometimes as the 'strawberry method/query' - although I certainly had nothing to do with its invention! But times change. The uncorrelated subquery method is almost always fast*er* (but not always fast*est*)